# Knowing which column is being updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am trying to get handsontable to give me which column is being updated, but have not been able to find a proper solution. I understand they are using a textarea to get the input and then putting the values into a table, but I just cannot figure out how to find out which column is being update.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will tell you what row/column is selected:

```
$('#example1grid').handsontable('getSelected')
```

This will be return the same coordinates as the currently edited cell, except for cases when there are multiple cells selected (but even then the currenyly edited cell is always within selected cells).

I am thinking about creating a new method `getCurrent` or callback `onBeginEditing` to return currently edited cell. Which would be better for you? I think the callback would be better.

Comment: I was looking for something more like onFinishEditing because the table contains data sets, and each column needs to be treated as a desperate data set. I was looking and I think your finishEditing function could be used for this purpose. I can call the function that requires the column number at the end if this, and pass in the priv.selStart.col and priv.selEnd.col. the first parameter would give the left most column that was editted, and the 2nd would give the right most column editted. I believe that would handle all the cases where the table is being altered.

Comment: Actually, just realized that doesnt work all the time. If you have any other ways to do this, let me know.

Comment: is `onChange` callback not good for you then? It gets an array of arrays as parameter. The array inside has structure `[row, col, oldVal, newVal]`  
  
Could you please describe your case in more detail?

Comment: The issue with onChange is that it does not trigger on all changes. for example, if I select a cell/cells and delete the data in them with the backspace key, onChange is not called. What I want is that any time the data array (retrieved using getData) changes, I want to know which column of data has changed, and be able to call a function that will use that information.

Comment: onChange should be called also when you delete the cell data with backspace key. If not, that should be considered as a bug to fix because the purpose of on change should be to trigger on all data change. See the "Validation" example on page http://warpech.github.com/jquery-handsontable/#example6 - I see the notification also when I delete the cell with backspace

Comment: So I downloaded the .js file again and the getSelected method seems to do the trick now. I must have messed up something while altering the code. I stil have to work on how to have my function triggered on every change (including after values are pasted/cut to/from  the table). Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: about your question I wish onBeginEditing and onFinishEditing +1 to your great software

Answer (score 2):

```
onChange: function (data) {
    for (i in data) {
        if(data[i][2] != data[i][3]) {
                var column = $('#dataTableLoc td:nth-child(' + (data[i][1] + 1) + ')')[0].innerText;
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously far from elegant. It will conflict with any extensions like the "removeRow" example in buttons.html but obviously can be adjusted accordingly. Its necessary when pulling data from an SQL table and trying to update using a query.